# UI is not updating immediately after performing dispatch_async on main thead?

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

This is my code :

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {

        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
        frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;

        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@x%@%@",
                                                        // some web service data

        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithData:data]];

        UIView *subview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

        imageView.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height);
        [subview addSubview:imageView];
        [self.dataViewsArray addObject:subview];
        NSLog(@"dwonload bacgraound");

    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
        NSLog(@"starting some UI updates");
        [self makeScrollPagingView];


    });
});
```

and     `[self makeScrollPagingView]` - is just  adding subview to my scrollview  ?
there is 10 seconds delay after my code is done . and then the ui is updated. Please help

Comment: Hey! You should do ALL UI-related code in the main thread. This also means creating your views/subviews and adding them.

I suggest to download all images in the background and storing them in an `NSArray` or `NSDictionary` and then doing your UI-stuff with this data in the main thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A faster solution would be to not load your images concurrently, but in parallel:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@""]]];
        CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((CFDataRef)data);
        CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithPNGDataProvider(provider, NULL, false, kCGRenderingIntentDefault); // assuming PNG format, JPG is also available
        CGDataProviderRelease(provider);

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
            CGImageRelease(imageRef);

            UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
            // Layout and position of just this UIImageView
        });
    });
}
```

but, depending on your uses, this might be a case a premature optimization at the expense of readability/simplicity. Create the UIImage on the main thread is probably good enough.

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@""]]];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithData:data]];
            // Layout and position of just this UIImageView
        });
    });
}
```

Have you layout code not depend on having all the images loaded at once. And like Sashcha said, never do UI-related code in a background thread.

Some UIImageView libraries or categories might simplify the code you need to write. [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) is a good one to start, it has `UIImageView+AFNetworking` that you should look at.

Comment: thank you :) .this is working smoothly :) but why should I UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image]; // Layout and position of just this UIImageView }); " set this for main thread. isn't this just setting some number  on imageView like frame ..etc .. and putting them into an array. why is this UI related operation.u just fill an array. i am not showing this view yet. Please explain why this solution is faster . Thanks in advance :)!

Comment: Every URL request will be contained in their own thread, so they will all be loaded simultaneously (not entirely true, you are still limited by the number of concurrent network requests and threads, but for our purposes we can pretend they are all concurrent). In your example, the images are loaded one after another.

Comment: Even if you aren't adding the UIImageView to a view, you still should not be touching them on a background thread. None of UIKit is thread safe. Some operations might not fail or crash, it still is against what the doc's prescribe, so it would just be a hack. Actually, UIImage is included in that, so I'll change the code to be inline with that.

Answer (score 0):

This code is not tested, but shows, what I suggest:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){

    NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        NSLog(@"Download in background");
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@x%@%@",
                                                    // some web service data

        [images addObject:data];
    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            CGRect frame;
            frame.origin.x = CGRectGetWidth(self.scrollView.frame) * i;
            frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;

            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
            UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

            UIView *subview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

            imageView.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height);
            [subview addSubview:imageView];
            [self.dataViewsArray addObject:subview];
        }

        [images removeAllObjects];

        [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
        NSLog(@"starting some UI updates");
        [self makeScrollPagingView];


    });
});
```